CSS Infinite Vertical Scroll for Arrow Image Background Without Gaps
I'm trying to create an infinite vertical scrolling effect for an arrow image (1101px in height) that scrolls from top to bottom without any visible gaps. The image is intended to repeat seamlessly, creating the effect of a continuously scrolling arrow background.
the image i want to infinetly scroll
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Heading from "../Heading/Heading";
import BodyText from "../BodyText/BodyText";
import infinteArrows from "../../assets/icons/arrowinfinte.png";
import './index.css';

const BusinessSuccess = () => {
    const containerRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const container = containerRef.current;
        const image = container.querySelector(".scrolling-image");

        // Clone the image and append it at the bottom for a seamless scroll effect
        const clone = image.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(clone);

        // Reset the scroll position when the first image scrolls up fully
        const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
            container.scrollTop = 0;
        };
        container.addEventListener("animationiteration", handleAnimationEnd);

        return () => {
            container.removeEventListener("animationiteration", handleAnimationEnd);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-12 h-screen px-20 gap-10 bg-grayBg">
            {/* Left Column - Spans 8 columns on medium and larger screens */}
            <div className="col-span-12 md:col-span-8 flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
                <Heading
                    text="Formula For Business Success"
                    color="text-neon"
                    font="font-monument"
                    size="text-50px"
                    centered={false}
                />
                <BodyText
                    text="Lorem Ipsum Is Simply Dummy Text Of The Printing And Typesetting Industry. Lorem
                    Ipsum Has Been The Industry's"
                    centered={false}
                />
            </div>

            {/* Right Column - Scrolling Image Effect */}
            <div className="col-span-12 md:col-span-4 flex items-center justify-center overflow-hidden relative h-full">
                <div ref={containerRef} className="scrolling-image-container w-full h-full absolute">
                    <img src={infinteArrows} alt="Infinite Arrows" className="w-full object-contain scrolling-image" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default BusinessSuccess;


.scrolling-image-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.scrolling-image {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 130%; /* Adjust to ensure the image goes out of view */
    animation: scrollVertically 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scrollVertically {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(-100%); /* Move the image fully out of view */
    }
}


So right now there are gaps, also image should infintely sccroll fine irepsective of screen size

Could you describe exactly what it is to look like on very tall viewports. e.g. are there to be multiple copies? (In which case use background maybe).

To get repetition without gaps or 'jerkiness' you need to be able to fit an exact number of the arrow image into the item that is continuously scrolling.
To cater for any combination of width/height aspect ratios of that final column this snippet animates a before pseudo element which has an aspect ratio with a whole (and large) height. The aspect ratio of the given image is 516/1101 so this snippet gives the animated pseudo element an aspect ratio 1/80 times that (in an effort to ensure it's high enough to more than fill any column height at least twice - for a totally general solution you'd have to use JS to calculate at run time).


<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  #arrows {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(100vw / 12);
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #arrows::before {
    background-image: url(https://i.sstatic.net/DdiLEyl4.png);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    animation: move 100s linear infinite;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 516 / 88080;
    background-color: black;
  }
  
  @keyframes move {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      /* when the item is half way to the top we go back to the beginning 
      so it looks continuous */
    }
  }
</style>
<div id="arrows"></div>



